# Laravel 5 how to run commands based on SQS message data

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5, amazon-sqs, laravel-artisan

I am trying to setup an sqs based message queue in laravel. 
I setup my queue.php file and messages are successfully being retrieved when I run the artisan queue:listen command. However, I am getting a [ReflectionException] telling me my command doesn't exist.

The message stored on SQS for retrieval looks like the following:

```
{"job":"HELLOWORLD"}
```

And I have created a laravel/artisan command with the same name as per the instructions at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues

```
php artisan make:command HELLOWORLD --queued
```

However, when I run the command

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

when the message is retrieved from SQS I get the following error

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class HELLOWORLD does not exist
```

My question is how do I get laravel to recognize this command and once that works, how do I get laravel to see other items in the JSON message contained on SQS. 
So for example lets say I have another index called "message" with the data "hello from sqs" making my json look like

```
{"job":"HELLOWORLD","message":"Hello from SQS"}
```

How would I go about accessing this other field? 
Thanks in advance. The documentation for Queues in Laravel is pretty sparse.

Comment: Why are you specifying the job/class name as all-uppercase?

Comment: Because I have no idea what I am doing. The queue section does not specify what a job (or a queue message in general) should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was doing this completely wrong. You need to use the `$contoller->dispatch` method as shown in the Laravel queue documentation.

If you do it this way the message will be properly formed and any variables in the class you create will still be there.